# C# Decimal Precision Improvement in Powers and Fibonacci

Tags: c#, precision, fibonacci

I am trying to solve the Fibonacci sequence with both negative numbers and large numbers and came up with the following code and algorithm. I am certain the algorithm works, but the issue I am having is for very large numbers the precision of the result is incorrect. Here is the code:

```
public class Fibonacci
    {
        public static BigInteger fib(int n)
        {
            decimal p = (decimal) (1 + Math.Sqrt(5)) / 2;
            decimal q = (decimal) (1 - Math.Sqrt(5)) / 2;
            decimal r = (decimal) Math.Sqrt(5);
            Console.WriteLine("n: {0} p: {1}, q: {2}, t: {3}",
              n,
              p,
              q,
              (Pow(p, n) - Pow(q, n)) / r);

            return (BigInteger) (Decimal.Round((Pow(p, n) - Pow(q, n)) / r));
        }

        public static decimal Pow(decimal x, int y)
        {
            if(y < 0)
                return 1 / Pow(x, -1 * y);
            else if(y == 0)
                return 1;
            else if(y % 2 == 0)
            {
                decimal z = Pow(x, y / 2);
                return z * z;
            }
            else if(y % 2 == 1)
                return Pow(x, y - 1) * x;
            else
                return 1;
        }
```

Small values of If we take a large number like -96 to get the Fibonacci for, I get a result of -51680708573203484173 but the real number is -51680708854858323072. I checked the rounding was OK, but it appears somewhere along the way my result is losing precision and not saving its values correctly. I thought using decimals would solve this precision issue (previously used doubles), but that did not work.

Where in my code am I incorrectly missing precision or is there another issue with my code I am misdiagnosing?

Comment: Changing a Decimal to a BigInteger will not magically increase the resolution of the Decimal.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I understand that, but the decimal type should have 28 to 29 digits of precision according to the documentation. The BigInteger is required for output which is why I do a decimal.round. However, the value loses precision within almost 10 to 15 digits so something is amiss.

Comment: Have you checked the accuracy of the intermediate values, such as `Pow(p, n)`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton checking now. I can verify that the algorithm cannot handle fibonacci numbers past the 68th value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static BigInteger Fibonacci(int n)
    {
        BigInteger a = 0;
        BigInteger b = 1;
        for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            BigInteger d = a * (b * 2 - a);
            BigInteger e = a * a + b * b;
            a = d;
            b = e;
            if ((((uint)n >> i) & 1) != 0)
            {
                BigInteger c = a + b;
                a = b;
                b = c;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes that is a pretty standard way of solving Fibonacci Sequence. However, this is not fast enough and needs to work less than a few seconds, not for minutes. Also, this answer does not answer the question I had about precision.

Comment: @RossGustafson I think you should review the performance of this approach, it should not take minutes. This is not the simple "add the last two values" approach. There are only 32 iterations this way.

Comment: I've tried Fibonacci(96) with result: Result: 51680708854858323072, elapsed: 00:00:00.0020192. What precision value do you expect?

Comment: This breaks for negative fibonacci numbers.

Comment: I misread your solution at first. I see what it is doing. Interesting solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. I investigated this and negative fibonacci's are the same absolute values but change signs whether they are odd or even. Learned a bit about fibonacci and finding bitwise patterns.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, `decimal` has approximately 28 decimal digits of precision. However, `Math.Sqrt(5)`, being a `double`, does not.

Using a more accurate square root of 5 enables this algorithm to stay exact for longer, though of course it is still limited by precision eventually, just later.

```
public static BigInteger fib(int n)
{
    decimal sqrt5 = 2.236067977499789696409173668731276235440618359611525724270m;
    decimal p = (1 + sqrt5) / 2;
    decimal q = (1 - sqrt5) / 2;
    decimal r = sqrt5;

    return (BigInteger) (Decimal.Round((Pow(p, n) - Pow(q, n)) / r));
}
```

This way `fib(96) = 51680708854858323072` which is correct. However, it becomes wrong again at 128.

Comment: So this gets me mostly there. This solves this issue for positive fibonacci numbers but negative ones still are off after about 10 digits. I am wondering if it has to do with how my Pow method handles negative numbers and how it handles inversion of a large number.

Comment: @RossGustafson that could be handled in `fib` itself, to avoid taking a negative power in the first place, though I'm not sure what is currently the problem with that

Comment: I am required to handle negative fibonacci numbers, handle perfect integer precision, and n values up to 200000.

Comment: I am thinking that my algorithm will not work because of floating point precision.

Comment: @RossGustafson Fibonacci(200000) has almost 42k decimal digits, a solution that relies on a `decimal` holding the number cannot even do a thousandth part of that.. Getting that many digits accurate is easy with the other answer to this question. Negative input is special but not a hard problem to solve.

Comment: I realized that now. I am going to try a different solution. Thanks.